# typescript: resolving typeahead.js with typescript and webpack 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I am getting the following error from webpack.

> ERROR in ./wwwroot/js/admin/infrastructure/typeaheadComponent.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'typeahead' in ...

I have the following installed

```
npm install typeahead.js
npm install @types/typeahead
```

My typescript is as follows, using `node` module resolution.

```
import { module } from "angular";
import "typeahead";
// necessary to import typeahead into JQuery, as otherwise
// typeahead below is not defined.

class TypeAheadController {
    foo(e) {
       $(e).typeahead(...)
    }
}
```

this generates javascript as follows:

```
"use strict";
var angular_1 = require("angular");
require("typeahead");
var TypeAheadController = (function () { ...
```

My webpack.config.js is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        "./app.ts",
        "./tab.ts",
        "./client/clientService.ts",
        "./client/clientSearchComponent.ts",
        "./infrastructure/messageComponent.ts",
        "./infrastructure/typeaheadComponent.ts",
        "./url.ts"],
    output: {
        filename: "./wwwroot/js/admin/admin.js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
};
```

imported into a gulp task.

How do I specify that `typeahead` is located in `node_modules/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this using aliasing. Minimal example of what to change  in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  /* ... everything you currently have */
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      typeahead: 'typeahead.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it solves part of the problem, the typeahead.js file is included in the output after it's used by the component so the whole import is still broken, and requires me to include the typeahead.js file manually anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The module is called `typeadhead.js` so you also need to import `typeahead.js`, not `typeahead`.

```
import "typeahead.js";
```

The import is always the same as the name you use to install it with npm. And it's not even special, it simple looks into `node_modules` and finds the directory with the given name. Then it looks into `package.json` and imports the file specified in the [`main` field](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/package.json#L67). See also [Node.js - Folders as Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules).

You could use [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to change the name of the import, but there is not really a good reason for doing that in this case.

Comment: this doesn't work, as soon as I change `import "typeahead"` to `import "typeahead.js"` the typescript compiler fails with `property typeahead does not exist on type JQuery`, as I explained in the question, the import is necessary because the type definitions are in typeahead, not typeahead.js

Comment: additionally, if I use `import "typeahead.js"`, webpack includes the file in the output, but the variable `Bloodhound` is not defined, so whilst the file is included in the output, the types in it are not accessible in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by making the following changes.

You need to import Bloodhound and Typeahead seperately. To do this edit your `webpack.config.js`

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      typeahead: 'corejs-typeahead/dist/typeahead.jquery.min.js',
      bloodhound: 'corejs-typeahead/dist/bloodhound.min.js'
    }
  },
```

And then in your `.ts` file:

```
import "typeahead";
import * as Bloodhound from "bloodhound";
```